# How to mock function for unit testing in serverless-mocha-plugin

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, mocha.js, aws-serverless

I am using aws lambda function and nodejs I am trying to test following function.

```
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

var host = environment.set_environment(env);

if (event.body[0].value) {
var cid= event.body[1].customerID;
var loginResponse = loginMethods.login(host,cid);

loginResponse.then(function (loginResult) {
  if (loginResult.hash) {
    console.log("login success");
    var Response = requestMethod.callAPI(event.body, loginResult.hash);
    Response .then(function (Result) {
      console.log('successfulll');



    }, function (error) {
      console.log('failure response');

    })
  } else {
    console.log("login response with no token");

  }
}, function (error) {
  console.log('login failure response');

})

} else {
  callback(null, responseMethods.error('Invalid request'));
}

};
```

When i am calling this function for unit testing, I want to mock the other function which is being called inside this function

For example in this line

```
var loginResponse = loginMethods.login(host,cid);
```

In unit test i don't want to call real function i just want to call a mocked function for unit testing 
I am from UI background to achieve same thing i.e to mock a function in unit testing in angular we can easily do while importing.

I there a way to mock function in nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to mock function in serverless-mocha-plugin for aws using nodejs

It can be done using sinonjs http://sinonjs.org/

Here is example for above function
In order to mock loginMethods

```
const loginPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  const loginRes = {

    "status": "success",
    "hash": "U2_a5da71a9-4295-48e7-b427-843c17c8cae3",
    "firstName": "Guest",
    "lastName": "G",
  };
  resolve(loginRes);
});

var loginMock = sinon.mock(loginMethods);
loginMock.expects('login').withArgs(arg1, arg2).returns(loginPromise);
```

In this way while test when this function will be called it will only call mock function not the original function and response will also be mocked response

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for, Thanks!